# How reset primary key in Active Record with SQLITE3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this problem.I create a table called Post and then I entered some records
How I can truncate the table Post so that the primary key again becomes 1 with out use rake db:drop

```
This code not working for me
$ rails console
> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE from sqlite_sequence where name = 'yourtablename'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the proper `yourtablename` and following name conventions. The table name is always lower-case and pluralized.

For example, if your model name is `User`, your table name is `users`.
If your model name is `Image`, your table name will be `images`.

Let me know if this solved the problem.

Comment: Ok friend. this worked. I had bad the name of the table.